# Combine SQL queries for efficiancy

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following queries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT goid, backid FROM trip WHERE userID = ?
SELECT goid, count(goid) FROM trip WHERE userID = ? GROUP by goid
SELECT backid , count(backid ) FROM trip WHERE userID = ? GROUP by backid
```

I am wondering if there is any way to maybe merge the 3 queries, or at least the last 2 queries into 1. Also if only the last 2 can be merged how can I essentially add the the results of the 2 to 1 colum eg 1011 => 20
as column backid and goid may have the same id and in this case the count should be added

Picture shows example output of 2nd query
The 3rd query is exactly the same but from a different column

Minimal example:

```
create table trip (
    goid varchar(255),
    backid varchar(255)
);

insert into trip (goid, backid) values ('EGLL', 'EGLL');
insert into trip (goid, backid) values ('VABB', 'VABB');
insert into trip (goid, backid) values ('KSEE', 'BHAS');
insert into trip (goid, backid) values ('EGNM', 'YSSY');
insert into trip (goid, backid) values ('OBMD', 'KSBD');
insert into trip (goid, backid) values ('EGLL', 'VABB');


SELECT goid, count(goid) FROM trip  GROUP by goid;
SELECT backid , count(backid ) FROM trip GROUP by backid;
SELECT DISTINCT goid, backid FROM trip
```

https://phpize.online/?phpses=ba9b2b20aab7889cbe83cb65527594e3&sqlses=9b7df2746f3828b9f34ae2ad42050b93&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80

In the example I removed the userid as its not relevant. But main aim is for the 1st and 2nd select queries in the example to be merged into one and the out put 2 be merged, ie if EGLL in goid and backid then they are essentialy 1 key and the count added together. Over all the 2 count queries should look something similar to the picture combined

[image]

Comment: What does `1011 => 20` mean? Also, it is better to post sample data and expected results.

Comment: @forpas added picture of the output of the 2nd query (and basically the 3rd)

Comment: The output of the 2nd query is not your expected output. What I asked for is sample data of the table and your expected output.

Comment: @forpas added an example https://phpize.online/?phpses=ba9b2b20aab7889cbe83cb65527594e3&sqlses=9b7df2746f3828b9f34ae2ad42050b93&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: Fine. Now, what is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas for the output table 1 and 2 to be merged into one eg output 1 had EGLL => 2 and output 2 has EGLL => 1 I want this combined so that is EGLL =>3 without having to run 2 different queries

Comment: What if they are different? How many columns do you want in the results? This is what I'm asking since my 1st comment? It would be so much easier if you posted your eact expected results.

Comment: @forpas added a different picture. In the example on phpsize the 2 count queries should comind to output exactly like the picture. (Order doens't matter)

Comment: Why do you want VABB twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to combine `goid`s and `backid`s and then aggregate:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT goid AS id FROM trip
  UNION ALL
  SELECT backid FROM trip
) t
GROUP BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16e808140df5c26773118b24d1f2aa9b).